# Can I configure Cassandra dynamically without having to edit XML to create columns?

Tags: cassandra

Can I configure Cassandra dynamically without having to edit XML to create columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-44 is open to change this.

Comment: This is brilliant. This was the one thing I hated about Cassandra. Any idea when this will make it into a release?

Comment: It's planned for 0.7, i.e., the release after 0.6 which should go beta this week.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra 0.7.4 is now current, and you can modify KeySpaces and ColumnFamilies dynamically via the CLI or one of the Thrift-based clients.

Columns themselves can be created on the fly anyway - they only need to be mentioned in the schema to add metadata features such as the validation class.